# Como esconder o keyboard no cordova ao apertar "Ir" ou "Done"

Tags: angularjs, apache-cordova, teclado

Tenho um formulário no meu app, e gostaria que após o preenchimento, se a pessoa apertasse `Ir` ou `Done`, o teclado desaparecesse.

Alguém já passou por isso? Ou sabe como resolver?

Comment: Você não consegue tirar o foco do input? Acredito que isso irá fechar o teclado.

Comment: @Oeslei na verdade sou desenvolvedor ios nativo, e o projeto q estou trabalhando é em angular com cordova.(Nunca usei antes) vou tentar descobrir como fazer isso, se der certo te conto. Obrigado

Comment: A ideia seria fazer um botão que simplemente removesse o teclado na página, e quando feito com sucesso, incorporar esse código nos botões `Ir` e `Done`.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor forma de interagir com o teclado é usando o plugin ionic-plugin-keyboard.

Um de seus métodos é cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close() que permite você fechar o teclado.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que com a ideia do @EduardoCalixto dê certo, mas precisa testar, claro. Mas a lógica é a seguinte:

1. Anexe um evento ao controle que vc quer que tenha esse comportamento. No agular é algo do tipo: `ng-keydown="expression"`, `ng-keypress="expression"`, `ng-keyup="expression"` acredito queo keypress se adeque melhor, sendo que o valor `expression` será a função declarada em seu $scope atual ao elemento em questão.
2. Na função anexa ao evento você faz o controle se a tecla clicada é o botão que vc deseja através do event.keyCode
3. Caso a tecla pressionada do teclado for a que vc deseja então vc chama a função que o @EduardoCalixo citou acima cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close()

Lembrando que vc precisa ter o plugin https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard instaldo para o metodo acima funcionar.
Boa sorte!.